# Given a mathematical equation that has *,+,-,/, reverse it

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm working on a low level Ruby challenge and it seems very straight forward however I can't figure out how to reverse the string and keep the integer the same.

The question wants me to reverse as follows:

```
solve("a+b-c/d*30") = "30*d/c-b+a"
```

My answer:

```
def solve(eq)
  eq.reverse
end
```

Output:

```
Expected: "y/b*100", instead got: "y/b*001"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `"y/b*001"` is a good start. Now you can add an extra step to identify the substring `"001"` and reverse it within the big string, so it becomes `"y/b*100"`.

Comment: @KobadaTech : I would break the expression into an array of operators or operands, reverse the array, and then join it back to a string.

Comment: Split the expression into operators and operands, i.e. turn it into `['a', '+', 'b', '-, 'c', '/', 'd', '*', '30']`. That array can then be reversed and `join`-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable names may contain more than one letter you may wish to split the string on the four operators.

```
def solve(eq)
  eq.split(/([+*\/-])/).reverse.join
end
```

```
solve("az+b-c/d*30")
  #=> "30*d/c-b+az"
```

See [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split), particularly the third paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def solve(eq)
  eq.split(/(\d*)/).reverse.join
end

source = "a+b-c/d*30"
wanted = "30*d/c-b+a"

p wanted
p solve(source) 
p wanted == solve(source)
```

I take the source string and split it up with `/(\d*)/`)

I get:

```
["a", "", "+", "", "b", "", "-", "", "c", "", "/", "", "d", "", "*", "30"]
```

See the 30 as one string in the end. `\d*` catches all numbers as one expression. The `()` means, that the splitt-parameters should be part of the result.

This array is reversed and joined again.

Comment: Thanks mate for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, if you have decimal points/commas and thousand dots/commas you can use: ``eq.split(/([\.\d,]*)/).reverse.join``